# Qt(C++)Ver.5でhttpリクエストのタイムアウト時間を設定したい

Tags: c++, http, qt

Qtでhttpサーバにアクセスするアプリを作成しているのですが
サーバダウン時などにタイムアウトを発生させる場合のタイムアウトする時間をどのように設定すれば良いのでしょう

以下のようなプログラムなのですが
単純にQNetworkAccessManager の受信イベント(onfinish)を成功時も失敗時も受け取るようにしています

タイムアウト時間を短めに設定したいのですが・・・

```
void MainWindow::on_btnQrequest_clicked()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *qnw = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QUrl qurl;
    qurl = QUrl("http://192168.0.1");
    QNetworkRequest qreq(qurl);

    connect(qnw,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)) ,this, SLOT(onFinish(QNetworkReply*)));//受信イベント登録
    connect(qnw,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),qnw,SLOT(deleteLater()));  

    qreq.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    QString strPost = "postデータ色々";
    QByteArray qr = strPost.toUtf8();

    qnw->post(qreq, qr);
}

//データ受信(失敗時も受信)
void MainWindow::onFinish(QNetworkReply *a)
{
    if(a->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
        QString str = a->readAll();
        ui->lblrslt->setText(str);
    }
    else{
        QString strEr = a->errorString();
        qDebug() << strEr;
    }
}
```

Comment: [void QNetworkAccessManager::setTransferTimeout(int timeout = QNetworkRequest::DefaultTransferTimeoutConstant)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setTransferTimeout) が`Qt 5.15`から使えると書いてあります。それ以前だとこちらの記事でしょうか [QNetworkReply and QNetworkAccessManager timeout in http request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13207493/9014308) 相応しい内容かどうかは調べてみてください。

Comment: 一般的にはサーバーに接続する前にサーバーのアドレスをDNSで名前解決します。ネットワーク障害だとDNSの名前解決に失敗すると思われます。その点は考慮せず、サーバーダウンだけを考慮すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。リリースするのがQt5.8なので(ハードに結びついているそうで・・・)、自力でやることになりました
そちらの、QTimerを使うのだとネットワークのonFinishをdisconnectする際に、スレッドの作り方によってはsegmentatin faultが発生するので結局フラグを駆使して受信イベントを無視したりするようにしています